# More efficient way to zero a device vector

Tags: c++, cuda

What's the best (efficiently) way to zero a device vector allocated previously with cudaMalloc?

Launch one thread to do it in the GPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Link to cudaMemset()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1ge07c97b96efd09abaeb3ca3b5f8da4ee)

```
cudaError_t cudaMemset ( void* devPtr, int  value, size_t count )
```

Initializes or sets device memory to a value. Fills the first count bytes of the memory area pointed to by devPtr with the constant byte value value.

Note that this function is asynchronous with respect to the host unless devPtr refers to pinned host memory.

Note:

- Note that this function may also return error codes from previous, asynchronous launches.
- See also memset synchronization details.